# Firebase Messaging (Legacy) is sending multiple push notifications on a single device

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

While sending bulk notification to all devices (7000+) some of the devices are periodically getting same push notification again and again. We have implement the push notification messaging system as `Backend -> AWS SNS -> Firebase Messaging (Legacy) -> Devices`. On backend we do store the FCM token and SNS Endpoint ARN for each devices.

When we need to send bulk notifications, we loop through each devices Endpoint ARN and send message using boto3 SNS client.

Till the time of writing this question, AWS SNS does not support Firebase Cloud Messaging V1. So we've still used Firebase Messaging (Legacy). [In that we've updated the TTL and message priority assuming it will stop sending message after 60 seconds of published](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#lifetime). But we've noted that TTL didn't work on our case.

```
{
    "GCM": json.dumps(
        {
            "notification": {
                "title": self.title,
                "body": self.body,
                "content_available": True,
            },
            "data": data,
            "android": {
                "priority": "normal",
                "ttl": "60s",
            },
            "apns": {
                "headers": {
                    "apns-priority": "5",
                    "apns-expiration": str(int(datetime.utcnow().timestamp()) + 60),
                }
            },
        }
    )
}
```

Any help on why some of the devices are getting multiple push notification or how to stop this would be great. Thanks!